# Trying to understand the output of a list

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the output of this function. I know it's supposed to return the positions in which there is a run of length 2 but I am not exactly sure how to interpret the output.

```
fun1 = function(M,k) {
    n = nrow(M)
    m = ncol(M)
    runs = vector('list',length=m)
    for(i in 1:m) {
        for(j in 1:(n-k+1)) {
        if(all(M[j:(j+k-1),i]==1)) runs[[i]] = c(runs[[i]],j)
        }
    }
    return(runs)
}

set.seed(123) 
M = matrix(sample(0:1,size=15,replace=TRUE),ncol=3,nrow=5) 

fun1(M,2)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in the list is the output for a column, starting at the left-most column. The list of numbers (or NULL if there are none) gives you the row numbers in that column where there are two 1's in a row.

To interpret the sample output you have:
- In the first (left-most) column, there are two 1's starting at row 4 (M[4,1] and M[5,1] are 1)
- In the second column, there are two 1's starting at row 2 (meaning row 2 and row 3 are 1's) and also at row 3 (meaning row 3 and row 4 are 1's)
- In the third row, there are two 1's starting at row 3

You can check that this is true if you print our the matrix M, which given your seed looks like this

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1
[5,]    1    0    0
```

I hope that makes it clear.

By the way, in the future, try to format your code better with proper indentations and line breaks. I had to manually add line breaks to make the sample code work, but good job giving a seed :)

Comment: Oh no, sorry about the formatting. But thank you so much for your answer. It makes perfect sense to me now :)